# call sum in expression tree

Tags: vb.net, linq, sum, expression-trees

I have this query:

```
Dim test = result.GroupBy(Function(row) groupedindexes.Select(
                              Function(grpindex) row(grpindex)).ToArray, comp).
                      Select(Function(g) New groupedresult(g.Key, g.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x(3)))))
```

At the moment, I'm building this: `g.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x(3)))`

I have this so far:

```
Dim groupparameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Linq.IGrouping(Of Object(), Object())), "g")
Dim objectparameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "x")
convertMethod = GetType(System.Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32", New Type() {GetType(Object)})
Dim aggregator_expr As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(expression.Call(convertMethod, Expression.ArrayAccess(objectparameter, Expression.Constant(3))), objectparameter)
Dim aggregator_func = GetType(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
Where(Function(m) m.Name = "Sum").Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType.FullName = "System.Int32").First
Dim aggregation As Expression = Expression.Call(aggregator_func, groupparameter, aggregator_expr)
```

At the last row, vs says:

```
Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Int32 Sum(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])'
```

Sure, there is one parameter more. But if I remove the groupparameter, I get another error message. How can I correct this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

here a simple console application:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Module Module1
    Dim groupparameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Linq.IGrouping(Of Object(), Object())), "g")
    Dim objectparameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "x")
    Dim convertMethod = GetType(System.Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32", New Type() {GetType(Object)})
    Dim aggregator_expr As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Call(convertMethod, Expression.ArrayAccess(objectparameter, Expression.Constant(3))), objectparameter)
    Dim aggregator_func = GetType(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
    Where(Function(m) m.Name = "Sum").Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType.FullName = "System.Int32" AndAlso m.GetParameters.Length = 2)(0).
    MakeGenericMethod(GetType(System.Func(Of Object(), Integer)))
    Sub Main()
        Dim aggregation As Expression = Expression.Call(Nothing, aggregator_func, aggregator_expr, groupparameter)
    End Sub
End Module
```

As you see, I changed a bit the `aggregator_func`. I would like to call this expression: `g.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x(3)))`.

I have all together, I need only to call the variables in the right order. But I don't get it.

**EDIT:** The code can simply copy&paste in vs to see, what is wrong.

Comment: What's the other error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're looking in `Enumerable` for methods - that's not a good idea if you're trying to work with expression trees. You should be looking in [`Queryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable).

Next, you need to understand that the [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.sum) method is overloaded - and there are multiple methods which return `Int32`. You need to check whether the method has two parameters. Note that you can check for multiple conditions in a single `Where`. For example:

```
Where(Function(m) m.Name = "Sum" AndAlso
                  m.ReturnType = GetType(Integer) AndAlso
                  m.GetParameters().Length = 2)
```

Hopefully that should at least find you the right method to call. I can't easily tell whether that's *all* that's wrong (a short but complete program demonstrating what you're trying to do would help) but it should at least get you closer.

EDIT: The parameters you're using are all over the place. For example, you've got an `IGrouping<object[], object[]>` - that isn't an `IEnumerable<Func<object[], int>>` - it's an `IEnumerable<object[]>`. And you're currently specifying the arguments in the wrong order too - the target of an extension method is the *first* parameter. So here's a short but complete program that *doesn't* throw an exception:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Class Test
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim groupParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Linq.IGrouping(Of Object(), Object())), "g")
        Dim objectParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "x")
        Dim convertMethod = GetType(System.Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32", New Type() {GetType(Object)})

        Dim aggregatorExpr As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Call(
                convertMethod,
                Expression.ArrayAccess(objectParameter, Expression.Constant(3))
            ), objectParameter)
        Dim aggregatorFunc = GetType(Enumerable) _
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static) _
            .Where(Function(m) m.Name = "Sum") _
            .Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType.FullName = "System.Int32") _
            .Where(Function(m) m.GetParameters.Length = 2)(0) _
            .MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object()))
        Dim aggregation As Expression = Expression.Call(
            Nothing,
            aggregatorFunc,
            groupParameter,
            aggregatorExpr)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @derstauner: And what's the result? (It's not clear why you've got them all as fields, rather than local variables within Main, mind you...)

Comment: The result is an error message: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[System.Object[],System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Func`2[System.Object[],System.Int32]]' of method 'Int32 Sum[Func`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Func`2[System.Object[],System.Int32]], System.Func`2[System.Func`2[System.Object[],System.Int32],System.Int32])'.          As I said, I don't really know, how I should use the Expression.Call on this variables. Wether fields or loc. variables, this doesn't matter now. I wanted only provide a sample.

Comment: @derstauner: I've edited my answer with a similar program that doesn't throw an exception. I think you should probably start with simpler things though - I think you're getting confused with the generic type arguments and the order of arguments.

Comment: I think, I got it now, how the order of the arguments works: let' say I call Sum on g with a parameter. Thank you.

Comment: @derstauner: No, you're really passing both `g` and the selector function as arguments - `Sum` is an extension method. That's why the first argument to the call is `Nothing` - it's a static method, so it's not called "on" anything.